# Universal cover and Deck transformation of a complex manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, complex-geometry, covering-spaces

I am interested in universal covers of complex manifolds. Are the following true?

1. The universal cover of a complex manifold is a complex manifold?
2. The deck transformations of the universal cover are biholomorphic?

Coming from non-complex differential geometry/topology I only know so far that the universal cover of a manifold is a manifold and that the Deck transformations are smooth.

I am quite sure that the complex structure should lift to the universal cover. But what about the Deck transformations. In my book they are *defined* to be biholomorphic maps $f: X\to X$ with $p=p\circ f$, where $X$ is the universal cover and $p:X\to Y$ is the projection.

But is this definition a restriction? Are there maps $g$ satisfying $p=p\circ g$ which are not biholomorphic. In particular, is the group of Deck transformations still the fundamental group when using the definition as above (i.e. requesting biholomorphicy)?

Depending how hard this is to prove, a (good) reference would be enough.

Comment: Have you seen the proof for the case of smooth manifolds? Have you tried to assist that argument for your case?

Comment: Well, if you have an atlas on $Y$ consisting of homeomorphisms onto the unit disk of $\mathbb C^n$  whose transitions maps are holomorphic, you can "lift" this atlas to an atlas of $X$ having the same property; just use that the unit disk is simply connected.

Comment: Now, using this atlas, check that if $f:X\rightarrow X$ is a deck transformation and $x_1,x_2:D^n\rightarrow X$ are charts, then $x_2^{-1}\circ f \circ x_1$ is just a transition map of the atlas of $Y$.

Comment: There are non-holomorphic maps $g$ with $p = p \circ g$. But a _continuous_ map with that property is automatically locally biholomorphic.